# Why so we need service account in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Why do we need a service account in Kubernetes? How is it different from service? What if I don't use a service account? Can Someone explain with an example?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/):

> A service account provides an identity for processes that run in a
> Pod.
>
> When you (a human) access the cluster (for example, using kubectl),
> you are authenticated by the apiserver as a particular User Account
> (currently this is usually admin, unless your cluster administrator
> has customized your cluster). Processes in containers inside pods can
> also contact the apiserver. When they do, they are authenticated as a
> particular Service Account (for example, default).

So, basically a service account is to provide a application running in the pod to be able to authorize itself.

There is by default a `default` service account created which can be used by the pods to access the API server.

A `Service` is a totally different Kubernetes concept which defines the networking aspect of the Kubernetes and how different pods interact with each other or how the application is exposed to the external world.

You can read more about Kubernetes Services in the [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

To sum up, a `Service Account` is useful to manage the security aspect of the Kubernetes cluster while a `Service` is used to manage the networking aspect of the cluster.